# Тип переменной для поинтера в С

Tags: c, указатели, типы-данных

Если мы декларируем int* x, то в этом случае х-это поинтер на int или x-это сам int?

Comment: в этом случае х-это поинтер на int

Comment: На всякицй случай, если объявите `int * x, y;`, то `x` - указатель, а `y` - просто `int`. Звездочка относится к переменной, а нет к типу.

Answer (score 1):

int* x - это указатель (поинтер). Самое сложное, лично для меня, это осознать, что указатели - это отдельный тип данных. Он указывает на ячейку в памяти, в которой лежит переменная того же типа, что и указатель.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


    int main() {
      int *x;

      int a = 20;

      x = &a;
      printf("%d\n", *x);
      return 0;

    }
```

В указатель кладем адрес (символ &) переменно а. Затем, чтобы достать значение из указателя используем операцию разыменования (символ * перед х в функции printf).